# How can I make a numerology?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make just a simple numerology but I can't find a way without creating a variable for every letter like `a=1 b=2 c=3 d=4...`

Answer (score 0):

Letters are nothing more than a representation of numbers by some encoding. Since consecutive letters are representations of consecutive numbers, you could just take the difference between the letter to `'a'`:

```
def letter_to_number(c):
    return ord(c) - ord('a') + 1
```

Comment: This would be 0 based though. Since `ord('a') - ord('a')` is 0

Comment: @NendoTaka arg, off-by-one error. Edited and fixed - thanks for noticing.

Comment: the two most difficult things in programming are naming things, cache misses, and off by one errors